# adding filterfunction to filter doesn't work in typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to add a filter function to a filter filter.

I'm following this example fiddle which works fine but is in plain javascript.

http://plnkr.co/edit/zigptcUjJ2GhurAKFQ0L?p=preview

I'm trying to achieve the same code but in Typescript, without any luck: the function is never called.

My html is identical to the fiddle, my typescript is as follows

app.ts

```
module app {
    var app = angular.module('app', ['']);
    app.controller('ctrl', ctrl);
}
```

ctrl.ts

```
module ctrls {
    export class ctrl {
        friends = [
            { name: "Peter",   age: 20 },
            { name: "Pablo",   age: 55 },
            { name: "Linda",   age: 20 },
            { name: "Marta",   age: 37 },
            { name: "Othello", age: 20 },
            { name: "Markus",  age: 32 }
        ];

        static filterFunction(element) {
            return element.name.match(/^Ma/) ? true : false;
        };
    }
}
```

i tried with and without the static keyword without any luck, the function isn't getting called in both cases.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the filter function should not be static.

Secondly, I think that your main problem is the module creation. Try to replace these lines:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['']);
app.controller('ctrl', ctrl);
```

with these:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', ctrls.ctrl);
```

Comment: thanks, but module creation is not the issue,
app is created fine, and controller is registered and working